# How can i create a new div when i onclick the button in React js?

Tags: reactjs

code 1 component:-

```
const TableheaderText = props => {
    //const [playlist, setPlaylist] = useState(props);
    const [playlist, setPlaylist] = useState("playlist");
    const [showing, SetShowing] = useState();
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState(true);
    //console.log(playlist);

    useEffect(() => {
        // setPlaylist(props);
        SetShowing("PLAYLIST:");
        setPlaylist(props.val);
    }, [props])
    

    return (
        <div className="mainContent">
            <div className="tableHeaderBody"  >
                <div className="TableText"   >
                    <div id="HIDE">{showing}</div><div id="SHOW">{playlist}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="ClossIcon"><FaCircle style={{ color: "#FC0000", width: "10px", height: "10px", alignItems: "right" }} /></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

code 2 component:-

```
<NavLink to={`/Table`} onClick={(e) => myClick(val, index)} >
             <button className='notActive buttonLeft'
                      onClick={() => handleOnClick(index)} // pass the index
                         className={activeIndex === index ? "active" : "notActive"}>
                                        {val}
                                    </button>
                                </NavLink>
```

Right now i have one div and when i click the menu value then one div replace the name
but i want that when i click the 1 value its create one div and when click the 2 value its create second div with the name of 2 div and place right side of 1 div  and so.. (if 3,4 value menu ..)
[image]

Comment: "i" is your name. Please capitalize it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective (copied from OP's question):

> i want that when i click the 1 value its create one div and when click
> the 2 value its create second div with the name of 2 div and place
> right side of 1 div and so..

**Code Snippet**

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Thingy = () => {
  const myDivs = [...Array(4).keys()].map(i => `My Div # ${i+1}`);
  const [flipDivs, setFlipDivs] = useState([
    ...myDivs.map(
      (text, id) => ({id, text, show: false})
    )
  ]);
  const handleClick = e => {
    const idx = e.target.id;
    const newArr = [...flipDivs];
    newArr[idx].show = !flipDivs[idx].show;
    setFlipDivs(newArr);
  }; 
  const myButtons = [...Array(4).keys()];
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div class="allDivs">
        <div> Fixed Div </div>
        {
          flipDivs.filter(({show}) => !!show).map(
            ({text, id, show}, idx) => (
              <div
                key={idx}
                class="simpleMargin rightBorder"
              >
                {text}
              </div>
            )
          )
        }
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        {myButtons.map(id => (
          <button
            id={id}
            class="simpleMargin"
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            {flipDivs[id].show ? 'Hide' : 'Show'} Div # {id+1}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    DEMO
    <Thingy />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```css
.allDivs {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 15px;
}

.simpleMargin { margin: 5px 10px; }
.rightBorder { border: 2px solid black; }

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rd" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**Explanation**

- simple, straightforward approach
- Add a flag to determine which div needs to be rendered on which button click
- On the click-handler, simply update the flag to show / hide div

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to make a div element and whoe it conditionally ( with state declared with useState ) and then toggle the state on button click to show it. like :

```
{
  showDiv ? <div></div> : null
}
```

Here showDiv is:

```
const [showDiv, setShowDiv] = useState (false)
```

Now toggle showDiv on button click to true. :)